# Use StepMonitor and Dynamic to plot progress of FindMinimum

Tags: dynamic

The obvious way of plotting the progress of `FindMinimum` fails with an error about things not being localizable:

```
Dynamic[ListPlot[vals]]
vals={};FindMinimum[x1^2, {x1}, StepMonitor :> vals = Append[vals, x1]];
  FindMinimum::vloc: The variable StepMonitor:>vals=Append[vals,x1] cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values. >>
```

I am not certain of the usefulness of the error, as when I added the `StepMonitor` to a more complex `FindMinimum` expression (that previously worked), it led to an error about the `Gradient` (when I put the `StepMonitor` after the `Gradient`) or the same error as above (otherwise).

Is this achievable in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use AppendTo, I added a Pause since it happens so fast otherwise

```
vals = {};
Dynamic[ListPlot[vals]]
FindMinimum[x1^4, {x1}, StepMonitor :> (AppendTo[vals, x1]; Pause[.5])]
```

[image]